# How to get a glyph as vectors

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vector, glyph

I'm aware of the `GlyphTypeface.GetGlyphOutline()` in WPF but what I need is to get a center-vector of each glyph, like the lines you draw with a pencil. Is this possible somehow using the existing glyph's of a fontface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the glyph polygon and produce the so called Straight Skeleton of the  polygon.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton

For an algorithm, see e.g (Felkel 1998)

http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/mabellanas/tfcs/skeleton/html/documentacion/straight%20skeletons%20implementation.pdf